# GitLab High Availability (Active - Passive)

Tags: gitlab, high-availability, drbd

My client asked me for a high availability solution for GitLab using two data center. After to read documentation and to use google, I´m very very lost.

The GitLab documentation for High Availability with active active seems good but the active passive is only 5 lines where GitLab says: "Use DRBD".

Someone has worked with GitLab solutions with high availability?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I've worked with GitLab HA.

I'd recommend active/active HA because it not only provides HA, but scales as well. It's also nearly eliminates the case where a passive node may become misconfigured, out of date, or otherwise unhealthy and unable to take over during a failure, since it is rarely used.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I know active - active is the best option but my client only want to use active - passive. Two cloned machines with same IP, a shared NFS and one power on and the other power off.

Comment: I think you should tell them the disadvantages of passive/active ... and you may mention the last incident of British Airways where they couldn't recover even they had DR and HA plans... (you can google and find more details about this IT incident that happened two weeks ago)

Comment: how can we do HA across multiple data centers